# Full screen video display in Android webview

Tags: java, video, webview, androidx

I am developing an android browser using webview!
When I enter the YouTube site in my browser and click on the full screen video, nothing happens!
I want when I click on the full screen option, the video will be displayed in a separate section, full screen and horizontally!

Image of my browser
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20V6u.jpg)

Other people's browser image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OccDC.jpg)